# squid reply_header_access configuration?

Tags: squid

Can any one please explain what does the `reply_header_access` configuration directive does? (and yes, I have RTFM, but I still do not understand what it does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This directive allows squid to remove headers from the HTTP reply before returning it to the client. You might do this because you're using Squid as a reverse-proxy and you want to "anonymize" your web servers (removing the "Server" header, for example) or to hide the presence of the cache (removing headers like "Via", "X-Cache", etc, for example).

There is a "request_header_access" directive to do the same things to the client's request headers.

Both directives apply based on ACLs such that you can be very flexible in determine to which requests the directives will actually apply.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have two more questions that may know the answer to: 1) can I send a different header value instead of just having squid remove the header? 2) can i do this for the Cache-Control header as well?

Comment: This entry in the Squid FAQ should be helpful: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation   You can manipulate the cache-control header.

Comment: Found out that using ACL "it is not possible to replace a response header because the header_replace option only works with HTTP requests". Thanks again for the help and pointers.